# Trickster's attributes

Tags: characters

I am trying conceptualize character kinds. After several days of digging, me as non-writer found 20 attributes which most tricksters have. The list is still raw. I believe voice of others would be beneficial for my little research, so I am publishing the list in hope you destroy my proposition what will help me to make a better one. Here it goes.

Most trickster has attributes:

- In most cases curiosity, intelligence, and creativity are attributes of a trickster.
- Trickster led by curiosity or revenge for being wronged.
- Trickster gets fun satisfying his curiosity, putting in the second place rules, moral, conventions and other own interests.
- Trickster could trick others or could be too truthful character shedding light on what others conceal.
- Put himself in one row with God/Devil, has extraordinary power, exceptional knowledge.
- Encourage reader to think outside the box.
- Encourage reader and other characters to learn, gives tricky lessons.
- Openly questions and mocks convention and moral.
- Often a trickster disobeys rules or dictates his own rules.
- Entertaining yet sacred.
- Trickster fights against oppressive leadership if any.
- Usually has a fundamental role in creating a culture, changing rules of a game, a trickster is an agent of changes.
- Usually selfish, but not profit-oriented.
- Mostly all trickster are males.
- As well as clown could sometimes joke on himself.
- Trickster is an outsider. Outside society. Often alone.
- Trickster often takes what is expected and turn it upside down.
- Often much weaker others somehow, has a defect.
- The Trickster is extroverted despite being alone; he is very close to the MBTI personality type 'ENTP'.
- The Trickster can be both pleasant and cold depending on the situation.

As Nathan Coustenoble noted trickster does not have to contain all of this attributes at the same time. And also I should point that some attributes from the list more important than others, need to prioritize them in the future.

Comment: What do you mean by "Entertaining yet sacred"? Do you think it's a contradiction?

Comment: No it's not. Although that may seem surprising, see the wikipedia article for more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a pretty accurate list.
You may want to note that :

- you don't have to use  all of those attributes at the same time
- the Trickster is generally extroverted despite being alone
- the Trickster is very versatile, he can be both pleasant and cold depending on the situation
- the trickster is very close to the MBTI personality type 'ENTP'.

Comment: Oh, and on a side note, the Trickster often give up on revenge quickly, all the while remembering it in case in comes handy in the future, for example as knowledge of someone's past faults.

Comment: Many mangas/animes feature Entp tricksters, more than other medias. Although they are not always a fine piece of art, they depict tricksters rather well. (eg Izaiah from Durarara, etc.). Other references are, as you may have guessed The Joker, Jack Sparrow or Tyrion Lannister.

Comment: Nathan, are you interested in designing games?

Comment: Do you want to exchange contacts? :)